# How to know if I have required a library

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake

Is there any way to do something like this pseudo-code?

```
puts was_required?('my-library')
=> false

require('my-library')
puts was_required?('my-library')
=> true
```

I want to be able to test if I have required some library, whether is a Gem o or a Rake task, by it's **require-name**.

I could test a gem testing if the Class the gem loads is available, but I would really love to test using the library name, no the class name.

For rake tasks is the same. I can find in `Rake.tasks` if there is a task from the library I have required, by I would like to test with the library name, no for tasks names

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to play around with `$LOADED_FEATURES` (alias of `$"`), that array that contains the `module names` loaded by `require`?

```
def was_required?(file)
  rex = Regexp.new("/#{Regexp.quote(file)}\.(so|o|sl|rb)?")
  $LOADED_FEATURES.find { |f| f =~ rex }
end

was_required?('uri')
#=> false
require 'uri'
#=> true
was_required?('uri')
#=> true
```

Btw this is exactly what Ruby does in the `require` method.

Comment: Thanks! That `$LOADED_FEATURES` was exactly what I needed. I have a problem though with the rexeg you proposed. It doesn't find the required files, if I remove the "lc" at the beginning of the regex, it works fine. Any idea?

Comment: I copied this regexp from the source code of `IRB::Locale`. Therefore it seems like the `lc` is specific for the IRB console in which it works. I updated my answer and removed that part to make it work outside of the IRB console.